# Printing lines if a specific column contains values >0

Tags: perl, shell, unix, text, awk

I have a tab-delimited .txt file in this format, containing numerous symbols, numerals and letters:

```
MUT 124 GET 288478  0   *       =   288478  0
MUT 15  GET 514675  0   75MH    =   514637  -113
MUT 124 GET 514637  0   75MH    =   514675  113
```

I want to identify all lines that contain a >0 value in the 9th column (i.e. only the 3rd row above would be extracted) and then print column 4 + 9 from any matched lines.

Desired output (two column tab delimited .txt file):

```
514637    113
```

Is there a quick way to do this in terminal/on the command-line. If so, how?

I've only just begun to learn awk and perl so all my attempts so far have been nowhere near close. Not sure where to begin!

Comment: You can do this with awk easily enough. Show some of your attempts and explain how they failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy in Perl

```
perl -lane 'print "$F[3]\t$F[8]" if $F[8] > 0' < input-file
```

- `-l` appends a newline to everything you print
- `-a` splits the input into the `@F` array
- `-n` processes the input line by line

Answer (score 3):

Can be done with the [Perl one-liner](http://www.catonmat.net/download/perl1line.txt):

```
$ perl -anE 'say join "\t", @F[3,8] if $F[8] > 0' data.txt
```

- `-n` (non-autoprinting) - loop through lines, reading but not printing them
- `-a` (auto-split) - split the input line stored in `$_` into `@F` array (space is the default separator, change it with `-F`, ex. `-F:`)
- `-E 'CODE'` (execute) - execute `'CODE'` enabling feature bundle (like `use 5.010`) for your version of Perl

See [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for more.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` handles it almost automatically!

```
awk '$9>0 {print $4,$9}' file
```

If you need to specify the input and output separator, say:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $9>0 {print $4,$9}' file
```